# Connect To Wifi on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I have a fresh installation of Arch Linux.

During the install I used `wifi-menu` to connect to wifi. After the installation I tried to use it and it said I needed to install `dialogs` to use it - which wasn't possible because I currently had no access to the Internet.

As a side note the laptop I use is a Sony Vaio Pro 13. It doesn't have an Ethernet connection because it's so thin. So I am forced to use wireless.

I have read the docs and attempted to use `netctl` but it fails to connect and returns an error that I need to install `wpa_supplicant` - Again I can't install because I cannot connect to the net.

What other solutions do I have available in order to connect to my access point so I can download the necessary packages?

Btw, `iw` is not installed. It also appears `ifconfig` and `ipconfig` are not installed, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: You can [connect manually](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless#Manual_setup) to set everything up. If you need to install packages in order to connect, boot from the live medium and use `pacstrap` to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start the livedisk again, remount your drives archroot into your root partition and then install the packages you need and everything should work.

Comment: Here is a step by step tutorial to do it: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246086/128489